# How to print hex value of 255 in Unix?

Tags: unix, formatting, hex, printf, octal

can you please tell me

How to use printf to find out the hex and octal values of 255?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the `o` and `x` specifier of [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)

```
printf("%d %o %x",255,255,255); // prints 255 377 ff
```

If you want to do this on shell you can do:

```
$ printf "%o\n" 255
377
$ printf "%x\n" 255
ff
$
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that this can be done in shell too! I just kinda guessed he meant C (because, well, the OP mentioned UNIX, duh!)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
printf("%x", 255);  /* print hex representation of decimal 255 */
printf("%o", 255);  /* print octal representation of decimal 255 */
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, printf "%o" 255 and printf "%x" 255 works as you mentioned.